# MongoDB write lock blocks reads on secondaries?

Tags: mongodb

[MongoDB docs about concurrency](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/#what-type-of-locking-does-mongodb-use) state that the DB is 'write greedy'. That is something I understand. However it does not tell about what locks do to secondaries in a replica set.

Taking my use-case which would get about 40 writes per 100 queries wherein I am not in need of having the most recent document at all times. A lag of 5-10 seconds is okay with me which is how much the  secondaries in a replica set would be behind the master. Now if the write lock locks down master as well as the replicas, then I am locked out of reads on secondaries as well.

I wanted to know if writers will lock read operations on secondaries as well.

Comment: The write lock will only lock down the primary, not secondaries, the secondaries will lock when they replicate from the oplog sometime later, this should ease the concurrent writes and reads as you said by reading from the secondary at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Into a replica set SECONDARY servers are not affected by the write lock on MASTERS.
You can see the status of your servers by using mongotop or montostat.

Comment: I asked the question specifically because I do not have the resources to run multiple instances :( Also, I am quite new to MongoDB. Yes, I have been following the entire development (no code, just the docs) but I started using it quite recently. So even on the knowledge front, I am a little behind.

Answer (score 1):

The locks are per mongod instance. That means that the read/write locks are locking operations only on the primary. The secondaries are reading oplog from primary and replicating actions from the primary.

You can read much more details on their manual about [concurrency](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/).

Comment: Using Version 2.4. Also have gone through most of their docs but this part "Do writer locks disable reads on secondaries" is not answered anywhere.

Comment: I am unsure how the global lock effects how secondaries are locked in replication

Comment: @Sammaye - I was referring to MongoDB versions prior to 2.2, where there was only 1 global lock. So a locking operating on one db will lock all databases (including oplog). But as you said in your comment - locking on primary will only lock primary and secondaries will be locked later on when the operation from the oplog is executed.

Comment: The question was about the latter, not about whether there was a global lock or not...I mean you answered a question, just I don't think you answered this one.

Comment: @Sammaye the OP is asking specifically for this - "I wanted to know if writers will lock read operations on secondaries as well." In my update I have answered it directly - locks are per mongod instance and writers will block only primary. You are free to provide your own answer or edit mine if you think I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Your update was done after my comment and provides no extra information or external sources to back up your information, you may have just reworded my comment and placed an update, any part which is supported by evidence and external sources prior to my comment does not answer the question at all

Comment: Why are you guys fighting?

Comment: We're not fighting (at least I'm not fighting) we're just discussing my answer.

@Sammaye sorry, but I posted my edit hours before your comment. My sources are MongoDB documentation about concurrency (specifically "How does concurrency affect a replica set primary?" and "How does concurrency affect secondaries?" sections).

Comment: @VaibhavKaushal I wasn't fighting either

Comment: @Sammaye I have edited my question and removed the part that was not directly relevant to the question. I hope it's clearer now :)